# Trouble installing a package using pip

Tags: pip, download

I've been using pip install for everything and it's been working fine but the last module I tried to  download didn't complete and I wasn't able to figure out why. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
Downloading/unpacking fut
  Downloading fut-0.0.20.tar.gz
  Running setup.py (path:/private/tmp/pip_build_root/fut/setup.py) egg_info for package fut
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 17, in <module>
  File "/private/tmp/pip_build_root/fut/setup.py", line 25, in <module>
    with open('CHANGELOG.rst') as f2:
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'CHANGELOG.rst'
Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
Traceback (most recent call last):

 File "<string>", line 17, in <module>

 File "/private/tmp/pip_build_root/fut/setup.py", line 25, in <module>

with open('CHANGELOG.rst') as f2:

IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'CHANGELOG.rst'
```

---

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error using pip a couple of days ago.

> IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'CHANGELOG.rst'

I just simply created an empty file 'CHANGELOG.rst' and pip installation went on normaly. Don't think this is a legit solution, but might be okay as a 'work-around'.